# pivot Table , calculated field

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

this is my probleme :

[image: Data base]

i get from the data base this pivot table : 
[image: pivot tablz]

i want to insert a row in the end of each groupe  tha calculat ( Nombre de responsable for each groupe  / total somme type a-month ) .

for example : 
for the groupe A in avr  :
( Nombre de responsable for groupe A  / total somme type a-month ) = 1/2 = 0.5

how can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, if you want to add a calculation to your Pivot Table, you would use a Calculated Field.

As powerful as Pivot Tables are, their Achilles Heel is the inability to use aggregated values other than SUM in their calculated fields. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402177/pivot-calculated-formula-sumfield1-avgfield2) and [this web page](http://www.contextures.com/excel-pivot-table-calculated-field.html).

Of note:

**Limitations**

- Calculated field formulas cannot refer to the pivot table totals or
  subtotals
- Calculated field formulas cannot refer to worksheet cells by address
  or by name.
- Sum is the only function available for a calculated field.

If you want to add your calculation to the table, you would need to do it along side, below, or above the table with a formula such as ...

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Count of responsible",$A$3,"responsible","A","Months",5)/GETPIVOTDATA("Sum of type a-month",$A$3,"responsible","A","Months",5)
```

These formulas are easy to construct as you only need to type `=` into the cell you want the formula then click into the PivotTable to get the reference to the PivotTable `GETPIVOTDATA(...)`

Another alternative is to add a column to your original data set and include it in your pivot table.

Comment: thank you for your response , i wish use the second alternative , to add a column to the data set and include it to the pivot table . do you have a proposal to helpe me to  achieve  that please ?   thanks a lot