# Pivot Calculated formula: cont(Field1)/AVG(Field2)

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2007

i have thise DATA BASE [image: DATA BASE]

The column E is a helper  to the calculation for the column F which allows us to calculate how much type(chap) handled a month , the formulas are showing in red.

i creat form this data base this pivot table , and wath i need is row that calculate `count (resp) / average (NB type a month)` that's mean `(row 1) / (row 2)` in french `(Nombre de RESP)/(Moyenne de NB type a month)` .
[image: this is the pivot table]

As you can see i creat a calculated feild that typically can do this but it's give me wrong aswer :

[image: this is the calculted feild]

i wish a can amend or add helper column in my data base to acheive wath i need 
or get the rigth formula , i want to do that in pivot table please .

thanks a lot for your answers ....

Comment: It seems to me that this is your problem: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/211470

Comment: You can't do that in a regular pivot table (the calculated field will always sum). Do you have Power Pivot?

Comment: i think it possible with calclated field (sum) , but i  have to add helper column in my data base , this is an exmple : [link ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12402177/pivot-calculated-formula-sumfield1-avgfield2).    i didn't undertand  the solution

Comment: i don't have Power pivot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i get the answer : the solution is to add a clumn to the data base , calculate how many "resp" each month , then insert it to the pivot tabale and do the ratio :) [image: data base with helper]

[image: new pivot table with the right calculations]