# Add a %Completed summary column to Excel pivot table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pivot-table

I have the following Excel pivot table that shows Effort by Workflow Stage for the Features in an app we are developing. There is an external column to calculate the %-Effort-Completed, which divides the value in 4-Done by the Grand Total for each row.

I'd like to have this summary calculation as part of the actual pivot table. Is there a way to do this? There's a chance that the external %Completed column could be wiped out if the pivot table were changed.

I've tried:

Inserting a calculated field with a formula to do the calculation. This resulted in the new field being added for each workflow value (1-New, 2-Approved, etc.). I only want 1 new column that appears between 4-Done and Grand Total.

[image]

Comment: this can help you -> https://stackoverflow.com/q/12402177

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have any luck with the link provided in the comments. I created a calculated item for the pivot table, but that added 4 columns, one for each of our workflow stages. Ultimately, I added columns to my source data for In Progress Effort (sum of New, Approved, Committed) and Completed Effort (Done). From there I was able to create a pivot table Calculated Field where I derived the percentages I wanted.